# Does bitrate also mean the internet speed I need to have?

Tags: ffmpeg, bitrate

I am streaming raw video at `-r 30` and the bitrate is as follows

```
frame=  228 fps=6.3 q=-1.0 Lsize=  410406kB time=00:00:31.03 bitrate=108341.2kbits/s
```

Does that mean that I need 100Mb/s internet to support sending raw frame, that bitrate is also the internet speed I need to have? And since my internet cannot support the fps drops to 6.3 instead of 30?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. But you should have a little overhead as well, so you probably need about 150Mbps for this. Something like huffyuv could give about a 50% reduction, or a lossy codec would give 95% or more reduction.